# Wordpress + CiviCRM: Restrict “Membership Renewal” contribution page to logged in users only

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions, auto-renew, renewals, gift-memberships

A Wordpress + CiviCRM site I'm working on has their "Renew your membership" page wide open to all users. We need this page to only show if the user is logged in for obvious reasons. What's the proper way to accomplish this page specific restriction?

My first thought is to restrict "CiviContriubte: make online contributions" in WordPress Access Control (CiviCRM >> Administer CiviCRM >> Access Control >> WordPress Access Control) but we may want some contribution pages (donate) to be open to anonymous users.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is odd as I feel i have commented on an identical question but i can't find it. maybe it was in SE. A 'renew' page is just as public as a 'join' page for the reason that it is the same page, and it becomes a 'renew' page when the person arriving on the page, either due to being logged in, or using a checksum, already has a membership. Can you explain why you say 'we need this page to only to show if the user is logged in for "obvious reason"'. as those reasons may not follow for all civi projects

Comment: ironically my colleague has pointed out we have done pretty much the same for a client previously and estimates it would take ~ 1 hour to generalise the solution and be able to release it as an extension if you are at all interested

Comment: @petednz-fuzion The problem is that users who don't have a membership try to "renew" their membership that doesn't exist. At least in my example, the page is dedicated to renewal, so it stands to reason that it should only be available to members.

Comment: can you clarify how you set up a contribution page to be dedicated for renewing only? but i am not really helping your core issue, which is you want to make this page only available to a logged in user, and i do not know how to do that. sorry